# correct syntax httpie request in windows command prompt

Tags: python, request, httpie

How can I correct input this request in httpie in windows command prompt?

http POST http://localhost:1337/api/articles title=TestArticle author='John Doe' description='lorem ipsum dolar sit amet' images:='[{"kind":"thumbnail", "url":"http://habrahabr.ru/images/write-topic.png"}, {"kind":"detail", "url":"http://habrahabr.ru/images/write-topic.png"}]'

but I'm getting error: http: error: argument REQUEST_ITEM: "Doe'" is not a valid value

I replaced all one quotes on double quotes

http POST http://localhost:1337/api/articles title=TestArticle author="John Doe" description="lorem ipsum dolar sit amet" images:="[{"kind":"thumbnail", "url":"http://habrahabr.ru/images/write-topic.png"}, {"kind":"detail", "url":"http://habrahabr.ru/images/write-topic.png"}]"

but it isn't working too, in this case I'm getting error:

http: error: "images:=[{kind:thumbnail, url:http://habrahabr.ru/images/write-topic.png}, {kind:detail, url:http://habrahabr.ru/images/write-topic.png}]": Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Comment: Try escaping the inner double quotes... `"images=[{\"kind\"... `

Comment: I found working solution for me, I replaced all one quotes on double quotes and everywhere added double quotes:

example:
http POST http://localhost:1337/api/articles title=NewArticle author="John Doe" description="Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet" images:="[{""kind"":""thumbnail"", ""url"":""http://habrahabr.ru/images/write-topic.png""}, {""kind"":""detail"", ""url"":""http://habrahabr.ru/images/write-topic.png""}]"